# Create columns with specific format in xml?

Tags: android, android-layout

Sample Screenshot
[image]

How to create this format using any Layout.

Comment: You see i am already tried this. I think, Is it possible to TableLayout. But I have no idea, how to solve this.

Comment: See [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Comment: you can also use  android:drawableRight="@drawable/crossImg" in your TextView attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout below will make the imageview take up just the space it needs and cause the Textview to expand and take up all remaining space.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal" > 
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:text="Welcome" /> 
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/yourimagename" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. It is a accurate solution.